# SQLAlchemy Using a sum function on a multiple joinedload operation on the child table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My DB Models are `DBServiceOrder`, `DBServiceOrderItem`, and `DBServiceOrderItemReceive`.

I want to write a query that fetches `DBServiceOrder` which is a one to many relationship to `DBServiceOrderItem` which is a one to many relationship to `DBServiceOrderItemReceive`.

In the query, `DBServiceOrderItem` I want to add an attribute to this called `received_qty` which is the sum of the `received_qty` in `DBServiceOrderItemReceive` for the given `DBServiceOrderItem .service_order_item_id`.

I have written the code below which returns me a nice nested object/model of `ServiceOrder` and its child tables. In this object, specifically the child object of `ServiceOrderItem`, I want to add the `receieved_qty`. How do I go about doing that in `sqlalchemy`?

```
async def get_service_order_by_id(
    session: AsyncSession, service_order_id: int
) -> ServiceOrderModel:
    async with session:
        statement = (
            select(DBServiceOrder)
            .options(
                joinedload(DBServiceOrder.service_order_item).joinedload(
                    DBServiceOrderItem.service_order_item_receive
                ),
                joinedload(DBServiceOrder.service_order_item).joinedload(
                    DBServiceOrderItem.part
                ),
                joinedload(DBServiceOrder.service_order_item).joinedload(
                    DBServiceOrderItem.component
                ),
                joinedload(DBServiceOrder.vendor),
            )
            .where(DBServiceOrder.service_order_id == service_order_id)
        )

        result = await session.scalars(statement)
        service_order = result.first()

        service_order_model = (
            ServiceOrderModel.model_validate(service_order) if service_order else None
        )

        return service_order_model
```

EDIT:

I made multiple attempts to try to everything in a single call but I could not. I tried the below and basically made two calls, one to get the `ServiceOrder` object (parent), and then another to get the `ServiceOrderItem` as well as the sum of the `received_qty`. I then assigned the results from this second query to the first object.

Not really feeling this solution but it is working for now...

```
async def get_service_order_by_id(
    session: AsyncSession, service_order_id: int
) -> ServiceOrderModel:
    async with session:
        statement = (
            select(DBServiceOrder)
            .options(
                joinedload(DBServiceOrder.service_order_item).joinedload(
                    DBServiceOrderItem.service_order_item_receive
                ),
                joinedload(DBServiceOrder.service_order_item).joinedload(
                    DBServiceOrderItem.part
                ),
                joinedload(DBServiceOrder.service_order_item).joinedload(
                    DBServiceOrderItem.component
                ),
                joinedload(DBServiceOrder.vendor),
            )
            .where(DBServiceOrder.service_order_id == service_order_id)
        )

        result = await session.scalars(statement)
        service_order = result.first()
        service_order_model = (
            ServiceOrderModel.model_validate(service_order) if service_order else None
        )

        statement = (
            select(
                DBServiceOrderItem,
                func.sum(DBServiceOrderItemReceive.received_qty).label("received_qty"),
            )
            .outerjoin(
                DBServiceOrderItemReceive,
                DBServiceOrderItem.service_order_item_id
                == DBServiceOrderItemReceive.service_order_item_id,
            )
            .group_by(DBServiceOrderItem)
            .where(DBServiceOrderItem.service_order_id == service_order_id)
        )

        result = await session.execute(statement)
        list_of_service_order_items = result.all()
        list_of_service_order_item_models = (
            [
                ServiceOrderItemModel.model_validate(
                    {
                        **service_order_item.__dict__,
                        "received_qty": received_qty,
                    }
                )
                for service_order_item, received_qty in list_of_service_order_items
            ]
            if list_of_service_order_items
            else None
        )
    service_order_model.service_order_items = list_of_service_order_item_models
    return service_order_model
```